# Sneaky patching source with Macports

Tags: macos, macports

For almost as long as I've been using vim and have known enough C, I've customised the installed vim to remove a 'feature' that annoys me. 
When I switched to using a Mac with macports, I achieved this by uninstalling any previous vim port, fetching the source, manually editing the source and then having Macports continue the installation, using my freshly customised source.

```
sh> sudo port uninstall vim
sh> sudo port fetch vim
sh> sudo /usr/bin/vim /opt/local/wherever/port/put/the/source/file.c
sh> sudo port install vim
```

Now[1] when I try this, the `port install` command re-fetches the code from the server, completely ignoring my source edits, builds vim with the 'official' source and the annoying 'feature' is still there.

I have looked for checksums for the source, ways to edit the checksums and command line switches to ignore them but without luck.

I have tried `port patch` rather than `port install` before editing the code but that made no difference.

I have even found myself reading the `port` source but my tcl is way too rusty to get far.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?
Thank you.

[1] Macports 2.0.3. I do not know for which version this used to work.

Comment: By "sneaky" patch, I mean that this is not a patch or fix that I am at all thinking of contributing back upstream. It is entirely for my own purposes and use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise to create a local portfile for vim and add your changes as a patch that is applied during the build process.

1. Create a local portfile repository: [howto](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories)
2. Copy the vim portfile directory (a directory called "vim" containing the file "Portfile" and directory "files") into your local portfile repository
3. Create a patch with your changes of the vim source code and add it to the "files" directory.
4. Edit your local vim Portfile to include the line `patchfiles yourpatch.diff`
5. Run `portindex` again in your local portfile repository
6. Install vim with `port install -s vim`

I hope this can help.