# Edit sources of a port before installing

Tags: macports

I have a problem with a certain port. It compiles and installs fine (`port install webkit-gtk`), and the actual problem occurs later (a certain symbol is not compiled into the library, but the details don't matter here).

In order to debug and fix this, I'd like to make some changes to the webkit-gtk sources before installing. With apt-get, I could do something like `apt-get source packagename`.

I found that I can call

```
sudo port fetch webkit-gtk
sudo port extract webkit-gtk
sudo port patch webkit-gtk
sudo port configure webkit-gtk
```

to do the individual steps of the installation. However, after I make changes to the sources I can't continue because I get error messages. I think there is a problem with permissions, as I can only edit the files as root (chowning to myself breaks the build process, and I can't `su macports` for some reason).

What I'd like to do is to make a few changes before the configure step, and then install the port with the changes as usual. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

you're almost there...

`sudo port uninstall webkit-gtk
sudo port clean webkit-gtk
sudo port fetch webkit-gtk
sudo port extract webkit-gtk
sudo port patch webkit-gtk`

before the configure step, make your changes:

`sudo su -
cd $(port work webkit-gtk)
cd $(ls -1)  #usually a work directory in here
...change stuff...
exit
sudo port configure webkit-gtk
sudo port build webkit-gtk
sudo port destroot webkit-gtk
sudo port activate webkit-gtk`

IDK what errors you are getting in the process, but they are probably related to the changes you made, not to the procedure.  You were generally on the right track.

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to get that isn't available as a variant of webkit-gtk?

Comment: You might also want to check this answer if MacPorts is in the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690159/sneaky-patching-source-with-macports